# How to display my block on search results page only if nothing found?

Tags: blocks, search

I want to place a webform block to make user able to inform about their special queries if no search results appeared.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7183631/display-in-block-only-if-there-is-no-data see this link, you will get idea!!

Comment: if you check the core default at **modules/search/search-results.tpl.php** you will notice the themplate of the search results page tests to the presence of search results, and prints the 'No results found' message if they are not present. You could overide the default using **THEMENAME--search-results.tpl.php** and insert your own no results handling.

Answer (score 1):

To expose a webform as a block, go to the webform, and under the *webform>>form settings* tabs go to the bottom, open up the Advanced settings, and check 'Available as block'.

Then go to **/admin/structure/block** find your block and click on 'Configure'. The url will have the form **/admin/structure/block/manage/MODULENAME/BLOCKID/configure** (MODULENAME will be 'webform', and the BLOCKID will have the form 'client-block-$nid' where $nid is the node ID of the form). Keep a record of these.

Then copy the core template from the DRUPALROOT/modules/search/search-results.tpl.php to your theme directory, and edit it to look something like:

```
<?php if ($search_results): ?>
  <h2><?php print t('Search results');?></h2>
  <ol class="search-results <?php print $module; ?>-results">
  <?php print $search_results; ?>
  </ol>
  <?php print $pager; ?>
<?php else : ?>
  <h2><?php print t('Your search yielded no results');?></h2>
  <?php 
    $block = block_load('MODULENAME', 'BLOCKID');
    print drupal_render(_block_get_renderable_array(_block_render_blocks(array($block))))
 ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

This will print your block instead of the search help if there are no search results.

Now, so your theme can use this new template, you have to make it aware. Edit the theme's *template.php* file and look for a function called **THEMENAME_preprocess_search_result(&$vars)** If it exists, add the following code. If it does not exist, create it and add the following code:

```
THEMENAME_preprocess_search_results(&$vars) {

  // ..... Existing code

  $vars['template_files'][] = 'search-results-' . $vars['module'];
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Download and install [Views block area](http://drupal.org/project/views_block_area).

From the module's project page:

> This module exposes all available blocks as a views area. This way you can add any block inside a footer or header from your view.
>
> Blocks that are generated by views, can't be selected. These blocks can be inserted by views areas.

To add a block as an area:

```
Go to the view that needs a block inside an area
Click on add next to header, footer or no result behavior
Select Global: Block area
Select the block that you want
```

Comment: The search results page is not a view.